# Meteor - MongoDB deployed query 2dsphere

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Using meteorjs, I can get this to work when I use localhost. But when I deploy to meteor I get the following error in the logs.

INFO Exception in queued task: MongoError: can't find any special indices: 2d (needs index), 2dsphere (needs index),  for: { location: { $near: { $geometry: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ -80 , 40 ] }, $minDistance: 0, $maxDistance: 500 } } }

Does anyone have any ideas why? I already ensured that location is in fact a 2dsphere type.

Comment: how are you creating the index? are you using `_ensureIndex` or how are you doing it?

Comment: It turns out that instead of using $near, $geoWithin worked.

Answer (score 4):

You need to setup the geospatial index first. You can do it in javascript code on the server part with `_ensureIndex` method.

```
        MyCollection._ensureIndex({ "location": "2dsphere"});
```

See more in MongoDB docs: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/build-a-2dsphere-index/

Comment: Slava, ask you here: does Meteor support MultiPoint or only Point in 2dshere?

Comment: no idea what MultiPoint is. Meteor supports 2d and 2dsphere

Comment: But 2dsphere can be different... I'm talking about this http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/2dsphere/#geojson-multipoint